# Hints of Visual Studio Does Not Show the "Dispose" method of SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dispose, sqldatareader

Hints of Visual Studio do not show the `Dispose` method of `SqlDataReader`.

This screenshot is captured from my Visual Studio. You can see `Dispose` method is missing.

[image: Please click this link to open image]

But I find `Dispose` method in this Microsoft documentation.

[SqlDataReader Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en/us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: The reference source for `DbDataReader` (which `SqlDataReader` inherits from) shows the Dispose method implemented publicly. The method is decorated with `[EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` to hide it from IntelliSense.

Answer (score 2):

`Dispose` has `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` defined on the [method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/Common/DbDataReader.cs,64).

Thus, Visual Studio "hides" it from you (even though it will compile just fine).